# Orca screen reader

Tags: 11.10, orca

I tried to run 11.10 on my desktop, and couldn't get Orca screen reader to read desktop screen without using the mouse. My wife is totally blind and has trouble using the mouse to find icons.

Switched back to 11.04 with classic Gnome desktop for which Orca works fine. She just has to right-click with the mouse and Orca works great after that, but this doesn't work with 11.10. Is it going to work in 12.04 when it comes out. I would like to upgrade but can't unless we can get a screen reader that will work right.

Answer (score 3):

Orca is supported, the accessibility team does try to make application authors aware of its existence and stop them breaking their applications when used with Orca. Right now there are some elements of the desktop that are not readable, I think because of some toolkit changes. Things are generally improving now, but the whole Unity/NUX thing was a setback for some time, as was the increased use of the Qt toolkit before it had accessibility bindings. We will publish release notes for 12.04 and commentaries of using the desktop with orca on http://ubuntuaccessibility.wordpress.com and that is where you can find some release notes on it for 11.10. You can also look at some of our documentation at http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accessibility or join the #ubuntu-accessibility channel on Freenode IRC